# Git: another lost-everything example?

Tags: git

I use git through the eclipse interface (since one year, not very confident, though).

I have a local repository that I push from time to time to a remote repository. 
Another developer is doing the same.
Today I pushed the last 2 weeks changes to the remote repository. 
The push was rejected.
As I know that the other developer is working on a different part of the application, what I did was a fetch of the remote branch and next a merge (click my branch and merge with the remote one).
There was only a small conflict that I resolved, then I pushed again.

At this point, I discover that I've lost all changes in my local repository.
In the history I can see only the last commits made by the other developers on top of my last push to the remote repository (2 weeks ago).

All my local history in the last two weeks is just gone.
All changes gone.
No recent logs. Tried with fsck, I see few files in lost-found. 
The other developer didn't do anything like rebase or similar, just push.

Any idea of what i did wrong, and more importantly, how to recover it????
Just some hint/guideline would be really helpful, I'm really under big pressure...
thanks

Comment: Unless you forced a full git garbage collection the stuff should still exist.

Comment: can u try `git status` first ? what did it say?

Comment: First, do a backup of your `.git` directory (so anything still there will not be lost).

Comment: I can  confirm that indeed everyhting was still there...

Comment: Is it possible you merged your branch into the remote branch, instead of the other way around?

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
git reflog
```

and see if it lists any of your commits. If it does, you can checkout the commit hash (say, `a4b82`)and create a new branch there:

```
git checkout -b new_branch_name a4b82
```

(And whatever you do, do *not* run "git gc" until you have found the commits and created a branch for them...)

Comment: yes, I did a git reflog show master which showed me in the first line a "reset -hard" (I didn't remember doing such a thing...).

Comment: After the "rese -hard" there were all my last changes. So  I performed a reset hard on the next commit: it failed with "entry xx not updated" on the conflicting file. I deleted that file and the reset restored everything. I still don't understand what I did wrong...

Comment: @Glasnhost Did you do a rebase-kind of merge(`git pull --rebase`)? When a regular pull or merge operation drops commits, you found a bug. Also it is better to stay clear away from `git reset` when you want to repair repo-side stuff (since git reset replaces the current branch pointer to whatever you give to it, which might not what you want). A safe alternative is to create a rescue branch for the missed commit with `git branch myRescueBranch a4b82`, and merge this branch afterwards into your development branch.